# How to set class attributes from list of objects in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have one ArrayList of PageSummary object and I want to be set value from list object to my Model class attributes using java 8.

```
public class XXXX {
for(PageSummary ps : pageSummaryList){
model = new Model();
model.setName(ps.getName());
model.setContent(getContent(ps.getName()));
model.setRating(getAverageRating(ps.getName()));
modelList.add(model);
}                   

private String getContent(String sopName){} 

private AverageRatingModel getAverageRating(String sopName){}
}
```

Here getAverageRating function return integer between 1-5 and getContent return string.

Comment: I edited your code to make it easier to read. What is your question? Your code seems to do what you want it to.

Comment: My problem is to convert it into java 8 
public class XXXX {
 for(PageSummary ps : pageSummaryList){
  model = new Model();
  model.setName(ps.getName());
  model.setContent(getContent(ps.getName()));
  model.setRating(getAverageRating(ps.getName()));
  modelList.add(model);
 }     
  
 private String getContent(String sopName){} 
 private AverageRatingModel getAverageRating(String sopName){}
}

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints:

1. create a PageSummary stream from the list
2. map from PageSummary to Model
3. collect the Model object

Here are some tutorials:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html

Answer (score 3):

First, you should create a `Model` constructor with a `PageSummary` argument.

```
public Model(PageSummary ps) {
    this.setSopName(ps.getName());
    this.setSopContent(getContent(ps.getName(), clientCode, context, httpcliet));
    this.setAverageRating(getAverageRating(ps.getName(), clientCode, context, httpclient));
}
```

Thanks to this, you can shorten the loop:

```
for (PageSummary ps : pageSummaryList) {
    ModelList.add(new Model(ps));
}
```

And easily use the Stream API:

```
// This solution is thread-safe only if ModelList is thread-safe
// Be careful when parallelizing  :)
pageSummaryList.stream().map(Model::new).forEach(ModelList::add);
```

or

```
// A thread-safe solution using Stream::collect()
List<Model> models = pageSummaryList.stream()
                                    .parallel() // optional :)
                                    .map(Model::new)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
ModelList::addAll(models); // I suppose you don't need us to implements this one!
```

Thanks [Alexis C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587046/alexis-c) for pointing out that using the `collect` approach avoid concurrency issues in case of parallelization :)

Comment: You should use the `collect` approach IMO. It suffices that one turns the stream in parallel and that `ModelList` is not thread-safe to run into concurrency issues.

Comment: In this I have two local method getContent and getAverageRating. Should I access this method in Model class by reference or something else ?

Comment: @PawanSharma Well, hard to say without the code, but you can pass the reference to the `Model`'s constructor (and so replace `Model::new` by a lambda) or make these methods `static`

Comment: @PawanSharma Sorry, I was speaking about the code of `getContent` and `getAverageRating` ^^ Furthermore, you don't have to post it in the comment, edit your question :)

Comment: getAverageRating function return integer between 1-5 and getContent return string.